# Design patterns for minesweeper

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, minesweeper

I'm trying to create a minesweeper game with design patterns, but I have trouble implementing a creational pattern for the tiles in minesweeper.

In minesweeper, there are 2 types of tiles, the number tile and mines tile. The number tile contains a number or a blank depending on the amount of mines tiles beside them. While the mines tile contain a mine image to load on the tile.

How I approached this is by trying to use a Factory Method for the tiles, here is an example in java.

The abstract class

```
public abstract class Tile {
    boolean flag = false;
    boolean opened = false;

    abstract void open();

    void flag(){
        // business logic
    }

    boolean checkFlagged(){
        return flag;
    }

    boolean checkOpened(){
        return opened;
    }
}
```

The NumberTile class

```
public class NumberTile extends Tile {
    int number;

    @Override
    void open(){
        // business logic
    }
    
    void setNumber(int number){
        this.number = number;
    }

    int getNumber(){
        return number;
    }
}
```

The MinesTile class

```
public class MinesTile extends Tile {
    ImageIcon mineImg;

    @Override
    void open(){
        // business logic
        explode();
    }
    
    void explode(){
        // tell main board to end game
    }
    
}
```

Client Code

```
Tile numberTile = new NumberTile(); // get and setNumber method will not be accesible
Tile minesTile  = new MinesTile();  // explode method will not be accesible
```

How do I use the same abstract `Tile` data type without having the child class methods inaccessible?

If I would abstract all the methods from `NumberTile` and `MinesTile` into the abstract class, then they would also have to override methods that won't be used and cause refused bequest.

How do I solve this design pattern problem?

Comment: If you call everything a Tile, you have to cast to a NumberTile or MinesTile when you need the concrete class methods.  Just put all the fields in your Tile class and make it concrete.  Some tiles will have a number, and some tiles will have a mine.  And that's OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot really solve this, I am not sure on the exact design pattern you're trying to implement as there are many variants. But the only way you can achieve this is by casting.

```
Tile someTile = new NumberTile();

if(someTile instanceof NumberTile){
    NumberTile numberTile = (NumberTile) someTile;
    numberTile.getNumber();
}
```